# Basic Pine Script plot lines

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to learn about Pine Script. I'm using Tradingview for technical analysis and MT4 to place my orders. I am looking to make myself an in-chart indicator that plots 3 lines (my order filled, my take profit, and my stop loss) at a specific price. I want to be able to go to the settings, set a specific price level, and plot the lines with the corresponding labels (Order Filled, TP, SL) See [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD7Mn.png)

I know this is super basic but I want to start somewhere and this will help me keep track of my orders.

Thank you in advance and thank you for not laughing, lol.

Answer (score 0):

of course it is very simple (see script below).
Perhaps you will be more satisfied with the tradingview's ability to draw long and short positions on the charts (see screen shot).

```
//@version=4
study("Help (lines)", overlay=true)

OP=input(0.0, title="Order filled")
TP=input(0.0, title="Take profit")
SL=input(0.0, title="Stop loss")

plot(OP!=0.0 ? OP : na, linewidth=2, color=color.yellow, title="Order filled")
plot(TP!=0.0 ? TP : na, linewidth=2, color=color.green,  title="Take profit")
plot(SL!=0.0 ? SL : na, linewidth=2, color=color.red,    title="Stop loss")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: If the answer is complete for you, use the recommendations of the article 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Thank you.